# ActionBarDrawerToggle No Suitable Constructor Drawable

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer, android-appcompat, build.gradle

I have simple code to create simple navigation drawer, but when i declare parameter for ActionBarDrawerToggle it's say that drawable icon cannot be applied...

Gradle Massages Build

```
Error:(36, 26) error: no suitable constructor found for     
ActionBarDrawerToggle(MainActivity,DrawerLayout,int,int,int)
constructor ActionBarDrawerToggle.ActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity,DrawerLayout,Toolbar,int,int) is   
not applicable
(argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to Toolbar)
constructor ActionBarDrawerToggle.  
<T>ActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity,Toolbar,DrawerLayout,T,int,int) is not applicable
(cannot infer type-variable(s) T
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
where T is a type-variable:
T extends Drawable,DrawerToggle declared in constructor   
<T>ActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity,Toolbar,DrawerLayout,T,int,int)
```

I dont know where i did wrong, i have see [support/v7/widget/Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) and [ActionBarDrawerToggle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html) but no help

I'm Already did like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19881510/android-the-constructor-actionbardrawertoggle-is-undefined) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639464/actionbaractivity-with-actionbardrawertoggle-not-using-drawerimageres)

this my import support library

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

This my Build.Gradle(module:app) dependencies

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
}
```

This my ActionBarDrawerToggle code

```
drawerListener = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer,
            R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Drawer Opened",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Drawer Closed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
};


drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerListener);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

This my Android Studio [image](https://imageshack.com/i/exI0m5xNp)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are two ActionBarDrawerToggle classes. The [support.v4's](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html) and the [support.v7's](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html).
Then, it is very cofusing, the v7's constructor methods are different from v4's.

You may fix it simply by removing the third argument *drawerImageRes*.

```
drawerListener = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
    this,
    drawerLayout,
    // R.drawable.ic_drawer, <== delete this argument
    R.string.drawer_open,
    R.string.drawer_close
    ) {

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Drawer Opened",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Drawer Closed",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

Comment: Awesome! this is working! But tell me, can we show Drawer icon and home up button together?

Comment: But now how to disable up action and show drawer icon ?

Comment: @geniushkg and FaizanMubasher If there is another problem, you can post and open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
```

to

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
```

Comment: Well this is the correct answer in my case. I had a " no applicable constructor" and changing to v7 worked!