# ActionBarDrawerToggle wants Activity DrawerLayout Int Int Int

Tags: android

I am currently playing around with the drawer in my new app and when I am setting up my drawer I am using the code

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close, 0) {

         /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
         public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
             super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);

         }

         /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
         public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
             super.onDrawerClosed(view);

         }
     };
     mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
     mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

However eclipse keeps complaining that `ActionBarDrawerToggle` wants `MainActivity, DrawerLayout, Int, Int, Int` and even though I have seen other Stack questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27922544) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19881510) use it the way I am and followed their fixes, I am still getting the same error.

Any ideas?

To add this activity is also using googlemap, not sure if that would make any difference here

Comment: You should have it in this order: `mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, X, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close)`. Where X is your icon for your drawer; usually your toolbar goes here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import `ActionBarDrawerToggle` from v7 supporting library, not v4 support library

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
```

remove this

```
 import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
```